# How to break graphview datapoint to get value of Y axis only?

Tags: android, android-graphview, linegraph

I want to break the dataPoint to get only values of Y axis.
right now the result i get when my code runs is :

Diastolic Reading: [25.0/89.0] mmHg

however i want to display it as:

Diastolic Reading: 89.0 mmHg

```
series_D.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
            Toast.makeText(Rsults.this, "Diastolic Reading : "+ dataPoint +" mmHg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break"? What view is GraphView, like where does it come from? This isn't a view in the Android UI toolkit.

Comment: what about using **right property(getter)** instead using object.toString() (which obviously is used when you are concating string object with other object)? ... very advanced hint: in almost all modern IDE you will get name of getters by writing dot after variable name (and since DataPointInterface seems to gave only 2 getters you will prolly choose the right one)... we call this magic intellisense

Comment: @Selvin Thank you so much. I have been able to make it work.
I used:    Double x = dataPoint.getY();
and then i put the variable x in the toast. Thank you again

Comment: @WadeWilson It is an open-source API http://www.android-graphview.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is now working as I wanted by the help of Selvin

```
series_b.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
           Double x = dataPoint.getY();
            Toast.makeText(Rsults.this, "Systolic Reading : "+ x +" mmHg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```